# Apache PDFBox Disable a signature field

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to read a PDF file and then disable a signature field in the process.

```
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
try {
    final int FLAG_READ_ONLY = 1;
    File file = new File("C:/sample.pdf");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    pdDoc = PDDocument.load(is);
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> acroFormFields = form.getFields();
    for (PDField field: acroFormFields) {
        if (field.getFieldType().equalsIgnoreCase("Sig")) {
            field.getFullyQualifiedName();
            field.setReadonly(true);
            field.getDictionary().setInt("FF", FLAG_READ_ONLY);
        }
    }
    if (pdDoc != null) {
        pdDoc.close();
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. How do I know if this disabling worked? Because, when I open the
   PDF I'm still able to sign the document.
2. `field.getDictionary().setInt("FF", FLAG_READ_ONLY);` I did not see a flag value `Ff`, so which flag should I be using. The documentation says `FLAG_READ_ONLY` - a `Ff` flag [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDField.html#getFullyQualifiedName()).

Answer (score 1):

In the process I need to save the document as well.
So pdDoc.save("Path of the new file"); -> worked for me and the signature field is disabled.